# how do I find the google app script limit to file reads

Tags: javascript, api, http, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I found the [Google App Script quota page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas), but I didn't see on there the limit to the number of file reads that can be done with Google Apps Script.

I know there is a limit for the Drive API which is incorporated with app script, but does the Drive API work differently behind the scenes in app script, with more quotas than would normally exist, somehow? Are there multiple Drive API "projects" behind the scenes, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quotas in Apps Script work as following:

- If you are using any API, e.g. the Drive API, the respective quota for this API apply
- However the Drive API quota has a `Courtesy limit: 1,000,000,000 queries/day` and usually `1000 requests per 100 seconds per user`
- It is highly unlikely that you will have problems with those quota, but if you do - you can request more quota
- Apps Script quota apply in addition to the API quota
- Where there are no specific Apps Script quota, only the API quota apply
- When you create an Apps Script project, a new[default GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) will be created for it behind the scenes, unless you [switch manually](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) to an already existing GCP project.
- In any case the API quota for this project will be the same as for any non-Apps Script project
- As you can verify yourself, there are no additional Apps Script enforced quotas for file reads, but you might encounter other limits, e.g. maximum script run time.

Comment: so to clarify, there are no read-only limits (besides for run time), but what about the 1000 requests per seconds per user, I couldn't tell from the answer that it also applied to google apps script, can u clarify?

Comment: `1000 requests per 100 seconds per user` are also a Drive API limit, not an Apps Script limit. You can see and edit those quota as described [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en).

Comment: OK Im aware they are a Drive API limit and I've read about them, but the question is does google app script also use the google drive API to read files, or something else?

Comment: As you can withdraw the documentation, there is only an Apps Script limit considering how many documents you can create, not read. However, for any king of Apps Script App (Drive App, GmailApp etc.) there is also a limit of how often you can call this service (no matter for whihc kind of request). This limit is not documented, but if you hit it, you are likely to get the error `Limit Exceeded: DriveApp`.

Comment: OK so this is where the question that was posted comes in: *is that App Script App service (Drive App, GmailApp) just an extension of the regular API, or something else entirely*? Just yes or no woud be good

Comment: It is something different. An internal usage limit to prevent abuse. There is no way to know when / how you might hit those quota, have a look [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/67697620) if interested.